# Didn't Red Hat Linux change its name?

Tags: rhel

I could have sworn that, a few years ago or so, there was some major news about Red Hat changing names, because it "sounded too weird" or something like that. Was it not Red Hat Linux? I don't remember what it was supposed to be called instead, and I can't find any mention of this now.

Did I dream this? Was it a major hoax? I remember long discussions about this and how IBM has put the last nail in the coffin of Red Hat, etc.

Is this yet another case of me randomly hopping between multiple parallel dimensions without knowing it?

Comment: perhaps you're misremembering Red Hat Linux splitting in two - to Red Hat Enterprise Linux and Fedora Core? (in 2003 apparently)

Comment: Originally, Red Hat sold boxed versions of Red Hat Linux directly to consumers and business through phone support. The Fedora Project began in 2002 as a set of community supported packages for Red Hat Linux. However, the six month release cycle of Red Hat Linux was too disruptive for business users and Red Hat wanted a more reliable revenue stream. In 2002 Red Hat began releasing Red Hat Enterprise Linux based on Red Hat Linux, but with a much more conservative release cycle and a subscription based support program.

Comment: A year later, Red Hat discontinued the Red Hat Linux product line, merging it with the Fedora community packages and releasing the resulting Fedora distribution for free.

Comment: The above comments from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux#Relationship_with_Fedora

Comment: Are you thinking of the CentOS Stream thing?  Not really a rename but it lines up with a lot of the popular sentiment about IBM and Red Hat.